# maxlength not working on a number field with samsung keyboard

Tags: html, jquery, regex

I have a `input` tag with `type="number"` i am using max-length to limit input length . It works fine on all browsers but when i use it in a Samsung phone with Samsung keyboard max-length doesn't work. otherwise on devices with google keyboard and ios keyboard max-length works.

```js
$(".numeric").on("input keypress", function () {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

  if (this.value.length == 3) return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="numeric" max="999" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".numeric").on("input keypress", function () {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

  if (this.value.length > 3){
this.value= this.value.substring(0,3);
};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="numeric" max="999" />
```

Comment: hey i think this will work . I will  test this on all devices and will update you rest